# Python simple encryption

Tags: python, encryption

I was trying to create a program which would encrypt a message according to a key or number that the user would give. So for example the letter C with a key of 2 would change to the letter E. I was thinking of using either a saved dictionary or ordinal values for this though I'm unsure on how to limit it to 26 letters. For example, my code right now would look like this:

```
word = input("Please enter a word")
numkey = input("Please enter a key")

for ind in word:
    encrypt = ord(ind) + int(numkey)
    actual_encrypt = chr(encrypt)
```

The problem with this code is that I want to limit the encrypt value to 26 and to have it start over again once it reaches there. So instead of 27, for example, it would be 1 again. I'm just a little bit confused on how to set that up. Thank you.

Comment: A simple way `if encrypt >= toobig: encrypt -= toobig`

Comment: But what if the key was insanely large like 100 for example and let's say the letter was C which would have ordinal 3. This would be 103 and it would have 26 subtracted from it but it would still return the wrong letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the modulus operation, `%`.  For example, `27 % 26` gives `1`.

Comment: Oh okay. I think that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right your word contains only the characters: a-z
if so you can replace the line:

```
encrypt =  ord(ind) + int(numkey)
```

with:

```
encrypt = ord('a') + (ord(ind) - ord('a') + int(numkey)) % 26
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the common way to solve this problem is using the modulo operator "%". This operator returns the remainder of an integer division between the operands.

It could look like this:

```
encrypt = ((ord(ind) + int(numkey)) % 27) + 1
```

If the result of `ord(ind) + int(numkey)` is 27, `% 27` results in 0 (hence the additional offset of 1).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.